# Is there anyway to run a specific await aciton prior to others within in the same function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

```
await ipfs.files.add(this.state.file, (err,result) => {
      if(err){
        console.log(err);
        return
      }
    console.log('profile hash ' + result[0].hash);
    this.setState({profilePic : result[0].hash , continue : true});
    });
    this.setState({loading : true,visible : 'true'});

    console.log('gender value is ' + this.state.gender);
    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
    console.log( 'the value of profilepic is ' + this.state.profilePic);

      if(this.state.profilePic == '')
      {
        console.log('waiting');
      }else{
        try{
          this.setState({continue : false});
          console.log('profile hash again ' + this.state.profilePic);
          await Patient.methods.insertPatient(
                accounts[0],
                this.state.surname,this.state.givenname,
                this.state.gender,this.state.age,
                this.state.email,this.state.language,
                this.state.nationality,this.state.phone,
                this.state.medicalno,this.state.profilePic)
                .send({
                  from : accounts[0],
                });
        }
       catch (e) {
        console.log(e);

      } finally {
        this.setState({loading : false,visible : 'false'});
      }
    }
```

I have this await ipfs add file to run first and then the second await takes the result of the first await and then proceed.
I want the second await to wait if the first await hasnt completed yet
Thank you

Comment: Await interacts with promises. Does `ipfs.files.add` return a promise?

Comment: I think it does not (?) as it only takes the arguments and send the transaction

Comment: Ok, then you'll need to turn it into a promise. I'll add an answer showing how to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for `await` to have any meaningful effect, you need to await a promise. It's not going to throw any exceptions if you await a non-promise, but it also won't delay moving on to the next code.

To take code that's written with callbacks and turn it into a promise, you'll need to wrap it in a new promise. For your case, that would probably look like this:

```
await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  ipfs.files.add(this.state.file, (err,result) => {
    if(err){
      reject(err);
      return;
    }
    console.log('profile hash ' + result[0].hash);
    this.setState({profilePic : result[0].hash , continue : true});
    resolve(result);
  });
});
```

Now that you're awaiting a promise, the execution of this async function will pause until that promise is resolved. Code later in the async function will not run until then.

If you're doing a fair amount of calls to ipfs.files.add, you might want to make a helper function that does the promise creation for you. As in:

```
function add(file) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    ipfs.files.add(file, (err, result) => {
      if (err) { 
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve(result);
      }
    });
  }
}

// to be used as:
const result = await add(this.state.file);
console.log('profile hash ' + result[0].hash);
this.setState({profilePic : result[0].hash , continue : true});
```

Comment: It works perfectly! I am relatively new to javascript. do u recommend to use promise for every await function? thank you ahead for your answer

Comment: That's the only reason you would ever need to do async/await. Async/await exist solely to make the syntax for promises easier to work with. Every async function returns a promise, and inside an async function you can use the await keyword. Await pauses execution and will resume execution once the promise you give to it resolves. Under the hood await is calling `.then` on the promise, which is the way you would interact with a promise if you didn't have async/await at your disposal.